# Issue with adding objects to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

So I'm having this weird issue with Ruby. I created a class called `Path` that has `start_node` and `end_node`. Then I created an empty array called `paths` and added `Path` objects. When I do`puts paths` it prints the list of start nodes and end nodes. But when I try to print each `Path`, it just prints out the addresses (it seems like) and not the start and end nodes. I'm not allowed to access `start_node` and `end_node` of each path inside `paths`. Here's the basic structure of my code:

```
path = Path.new(start_node, end_node)
paths.push(path) 
...
puts paths.to_s # prints list of paths and each path consists of start_node and end_node
# below lines of code prints the addresses
paths.each do |path|
    puts path.to_s
end
```

Are we allowed to create objects and add them to an array in Ruby? If so, what am I doing wrong here. Thank you in advance for the help.

Below is the entire script:

```
class Path
    def initialize (start_node, end_node, color, type)
        @start_node = start_node #start node of path
        @end_node = end_node #end node of path
        @color = color#path color (Red, Blue, Green)
        @type = type # path type (Horse, Cable, Trolley, Bus)
    end
    def start_node
        @start_node
    end
    def end_node
        @end_node
    end
    def color
        @color
    end
    def type
        @type
    end
end

class Graph
    def initialize
        @paths = []
        @num_of_nodes
        @num_of_edges
    end
    def read_file(filename)
        File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
            array = []
            array = line.split
            if line_num == 0
                @num_of_nodes = array[0]
                @num_of_edges = array[1]
                puts @num_of_edges + " " + @num_of_nodes
            else
                start_node = array[0]
                end_node = array[1]
                color = array[2]
                type = array[3]
                path = Path.new(start_node, end_node, color, type)
                @paths << path
            end
        end
    end
    def paths
        @paths
    end 
    def print_paths
        @paths.each do |path|
            puts path.start_node.to_s
        end
    end
end

graph = Graph.new
graph.read_file("./grandpaTransitInput.txt")
graph.paths.each do |path|
    puts path.to_s
end
```

Comment: Looks fine.. maybe post the model code.

Comment: You are trying to inspect the object. Write `p path.to_s`.

Comment: `p path.to_s` still prints out the addresses with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `puts` will call `to_s` internally on the given object. Your class "Path" has no definition how it should convert to a String.  Ruby will use a default method, which just prints some address.

But you can add your own method to do the conversations as you like, and `puts path` will use it

```
class Path
  ..
  def to_s
    "#{@type} path from #{@start_node} to #{@end_node} in #{@color}"
  end
end
```

The array is a special case, you should normally print it with `join`. If you print it directly, ruby is calling `inspect` on all elements. This is intended as help for debugging. That is why you see the internals when called on the array, but not on the single object.

Comment: Yes. I had to override the to_s method. I should have thought of this before asking. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me.  See where your experience differs:

```
2.2.1 :014 > class Path
2.2.1 :015?>   attr_accessor :start_node, :end_node
2.2.1 :016?>   def initialize(s, e)
2.2.1 :017?>     @start_node = s
2.2.1 :018?>     @end_node = e
2.2.1 :019?>   end
2.2.1 :020?> end
 => :initialize 
2.2.1 :021 > p = Path.new(1, 2)
 => #<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2> 
2.2.1 :024 > paths = []
 => [] 
2.2.1 :025 > paths.push p
 => [#<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2>] 
2.2.1 :026 > paths.push p
 => [#<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2>, #<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2>] 
2.2.1 :029 > puts paths.to_s
[#<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2>, #<Path:0x007fd6fa058d80 @start_node=1, @end_node=2>]
=> nil
```

Comment: Then when you do `puts p.to_s`, it prints out the address not start and end nodes. And when I try to access `start_node` and `end_node` individually, it's saying `p` is a nil object. I'm sure why... Did you try printing out your Path object?

Comment: NVM. My code works. I can access start_node and end_node. I don't know why I thought it didn't. But I'm still confused on why path.to_s would print the addresses. Thank you.

Comment: @JinOh Not sure what you're talking about. Ruby _always_ prints objects in the same format:  `#<ObjectName:HexAddress fields...>`